# How to show push notification dialog based on conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm frustrated of finding the solution about this problem. I have been developing an application that will prompt an UIAlertView to the user at the first time it starts. I want that upon user choosing Agree, then the push notification dialog appears. But the problem is the push notification dialog appeared at the SAME TIME that UIAlertView was prompted to the user. How can I make the push notification dialog appears only after the Agree button of the UIAlertView was tapped?

Comment: You need to provide some code. You're clearly using the `UIAlertView` wrong somehow but have not provided enough details for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Use the shared instance of [UIApplication sharedApplication] to register for push notification in your view controller when the alert view is dismissed. Then, the push notification alert will appear after your alert view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Use the shared instance of [UIApplication sharedApplication] to register for push notification in your view controller when the alert view is dismissed. Then, the push notification alert will appear after your alert view."

Thanks to [insane-36](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654666/insane-36)